# Not able to load and predict on images using YOLO inside celery worker

Tags: python, machine-learning, celery, yolov8

Here is my code

```
import sys
from question_detection.inference_object_detection.check_model import verify_model
from logger import logger
from ultralytics import YOLO


class ModelNotFoundError(Exception):
    pass


def load_model():
    try:
        success, model_path = verify_model()
        logger.info("model loading started")
        if not success:
            raise ModelNotFoundError("Model not found!")
        logger.info("123")
        logger.info(model_path)
        _model = YOLO(model_path)
        logger.info("456")
        if _model is None:
            raise ModelNotFoundError("Model not loaded!")
        logger.info("789")
        return _model, _model.names
    except ModelNotFoundError as e:
        logger.error(e)
        sys.exit(1)  # Exit the system with a non-zero exit code to indicate an error
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return None, None



def inference(images):
    """
    Inference on image
    :param images: It can be a single image, list of images or a directory
    :return: List of results
    """
    logger.info("started inference of images!")
    model, categories = load_model()
    if model is None:
        raise ModelNotFoundError("Model is not loaded!")

    res = model(images), categories
    logger.info("Completed inference of images!")
    return res
```

If I call inference normally it works like butter
But when the same function is called by another function which is a celery worker this do not work.
It even do not throw any error.

When debugging nothing is logged after `model_path` Basically not reaching `456` line.

Why I am not able to get the model loaded?